# Error appending record to a file using echo

Tags: linux, shell, etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I want to write a record using execute command stage in Datastage sequence job.
I am using below syntax.

echo "InputFileName;2021-03-25 06:54:58+01:00;AAA;Batch;FOP;FUNCTIONAL;INFO;Extra key columns sent in Key Values;201;OK;SubmitRequest;ERROR;CDIER0961E: The REST step is unable to invoke the REST service, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated;;SupplyOnhand_20210325065458;;;;0;CDIER0961E: The REST step is unable to invoke the REST service, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated;;;;12;1;2021-03-25 05:55:18+00:00;2021-03-25 05:55:33+00:00" >> Filename

Below is error I am getting.

Output from command ====>
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' sh: -c: line 0:` echo Unhandled failure (-1) encountered executing command echo

I tried running this manually on linux server its working there but failing in Datastage job.
Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape any character that is significant to the shell, or to contain the whole string in hard (single) quotes rather than soft (double) quotes.